# alter jquery animation direction after every page load

Tags: jquery, load, reverse

I have a jquery animation, where a picture slides off a envelope.

Now i would like this animation to go backwards after the page gets loaded again.

Meaning: the picture goes back into the envelope. then, if gets loaded again, picture comes aus again, ect...

How is this possible?

---

here is the whole code again. cannot self-answer m question yet, and commenting has too less signs.

```
var div = $("#karte2");
function runIt() {
 div.show("slow");
 div.animate({"marginTop": '-790px'}, 1000);
 div.animate({"marginTop": '-280px'}, 2000);now it works
}
runIt();
var div = $('#karte1');
$({
z: ~~div.css('zIndex')
 // ~~ to get an integer, even from non-numerical values like "auto"
        }).animate({
            z: -1000
        }, {
            step: function() {
                div.css('zIndex', ~~this.z);
            },
            duration: 2000
        });
```

Comment: now it works as i want it. i found a solution, where i can animate the z-index. after page load the z-index of the picture is lower again. probably i had too much z-indexes settings in jquery before. now i removed them all.
   
var div = $('#karte1');
$({
z: ~~div.css('zIndex')
 // ~~ to get an integer, even from non-numerical values like "auto"
   }).animate({
       z: -1000
   }, {
       step: function() {
           div.css('zIndex', ~~this.z);
       },
       duration: 2000
   });

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use some kind of server side language to save the state of the animation. JS will be reset on every pageload, so if you were using PHP, you could set a SESSION variable, and depending on the value of that, determine the direction of the animation.

Or, but this is harder imho, you can use JS cookies:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

If by load you mean a full page refresh, then you have to keep some server side state about the action to execute and dynamically change your view to render that animation.

On the other side, if you're using AJAX, just use a variable to store your envelope's "state" and animate accordingly.